# Hide the "new" column in a sprint

Tags: azure-devops

I have setup the process so that work-items are created in state "New", and once planned into a sprint they are automatically assigned as "ToDo". I dont want my developers to accidentally put items back in "New" while they are being worked on, so I want to hide the "New" column from sprints.

The "Column options" allows me to hide all columns EXCEPT for "New". Can I somehow achieve this or am I locked to the "New"-column allways being visible in the sprint board?